# Find the difference value between the longest time and shortest time of the same variable?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have fb.csv file like below.

```
"Source","Time"  
"192.168.137.174","12:26:25"
"10.0.138.163","12:26:25"
"157.240.10.13","12:26:36"
"157.240.10.13","12:26:36"
"157.240.10.23","12:26:41"
"157.240.10.23","12:26:41"
"10.0.138.163","12:26:52"
"192.168.137.174","12:26:52"
"157.240.10.18","12:26:52"
"157.240.10.18","12:26:52"
"157.240.10.23","12:26:53"
"157.240.10.23","12:26:53"
"192.168.137.174","12:27:02"
"10.0.138.163","12:27:02"
"192.168.137.174","12:27:07"
```

I would like to find the difference value between the longest time and the shortest time for the same "source".

Desired output;

```
"Source","Duration Time"  
"192.168.137.174","00:01:22"
"10.0.138.163","00:01:17"
"157.240.10.13","00:00:00"
"157.240.10.23","00:00:00"
"157.240.10.18","00:00:00"
```

Is there any method to that?
Thanks

Comment: It's needless to say there's a oneline solution out there, but I'd write a script to do that – beginning with this monster:
`source='"192.168.137.174"';sed -e /$source/\!d -e 's/.*"\([0-9]*\)"$/\1/' fb.csv | sort -r | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/-/g;s/-.*-/-/' | bc | sed 's/.*/'$source',"&"/'` – and to get a list of the different sources for the loop to work through: `sed '1d;s/,.*//' fb.csv | sort -u`. I bet `perl` or `awk` can do better though…

Comment: @pa4080 if you dont mind helping me with this. Thanks

Comment: You can't notify someone who didn't comment yet. Btw, did you at least try to solve the problem by yourself in any way?

Comment: @dessert, The sed command is entered for every source. The source is not fixed as I will capture more data. Could you help me by doing script that will operate with any source captured? Using awk or any bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's me again, the guy with the huge `awk` one-line commands... This one is even longer:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print"\"Source\",\"Duration Time\""}NR>1{gsub(/"/,"",$2);split($2,hms,":");s=hms[1]*3600+hms[2]*60+hms[3];if(!(($1,"MAX")in a)||a[$1,"MAX"]<s)a[$1,"MAX"]=s;if(!(($1,"MIN")in a)||a[$1,"MIN"]>s)a[$1,"MIN"]=s}END{for(idx in a){split(idx,ipm,SUBSEP);if(ipm[2]=="MAX"){d=a[idx]-a[ipm[1],"MIN"];h=int(d/3600);m=int((d-h*3600)/60);s=d%60;printf("%s,\"%02d:%02d:%02d\"\n",ipm[1],h,m,s)}}}' fb.csv
```

With your given `fb.csv` input file from the question, the output looks like this:

```
"Source","Duration Time"
"157.240.10.23","00:00:12"
"157.240.10.18","00:00:00"
"157.240.10.13","00:00:00"
"10.0.138.163","00:00:37"
"192.168.137.174","00:00:42"
```

---

#### Explanation of the command:

We run `awk` like this here, setting the field separator that delimits columns to `,` and using the file `fb.csv` as input:

```
awk -F, '<COMMAND>' fb.csv
```

The `awk` command (placeholder `<COMMAND>` above) is this, after proper formatting:

```
BEGIN {
    print "\"Source\",\"Duration Time\""
}
NR>1 {
    gsub(/"/, "", $2)
    split($2, hms, ":")
    s = hms[1]*3600 + hms[2]*60 + hms[3]
    if ( !(($1,"MAX") in a) || a[$1,"MAX"] < s )
        a[$1,"MAX"] = s
    if ( !(($1,"MIN") in a) || a[$1,"MIN"] > s )
        a[$1,"MIN"] = s
}
END {
    for (idx in a) {
        split(idx, ipm, SUBSEP)
        if (ipm[2]=="MAX") {
            d = a[idx] - a[ipm[1],"MIN"]
            h = int(d / 3600)
            m = int((d - h * 3600) / 60)
            s = d%60
            printf("%s,\"%02d:%02d:%02d\"\n", ipm[1] ,h ,m ,s)
        }
    }
}
```

- The `BEGIN` block simply prints the new CSV header.
- The `NR>1` block runs once per line in the input file, except for the first line which contains the header. Each line gets split into the IP column (`$1`) and the time column (`$2`).

  We process the time column by stripping the quotes with `gsub` and splitting it at the colons into an array `hms` which contains the hours, minutes and seconds. This is used to convert the time stamp to seconds since midnight, stored in `s` in this block.

  Next we check the associative array if it does not have an entry with the current line's IP yet or if the entry has smaller MAX or larger MIN time values, in which case it will be updated accordingly.
- Finally, in the `END` block the created array gets evaluated and for each IP in it, the difference between the MAX and MIN time stamps is calculated and saved as `d`. This gets converted back into hours, minutes and seconds and outputted properly formatted.

Comment: can you help me run my file. I'll give you the file. I got some error in the duration time.

Comment: Can you simply upload it e.g. to https://pastebin.org and share the link here? Also, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: here is the link; https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=tw1.csv    : I got problem in the duration time value, for example  "104.244.42.1","00:540:23"   "192.168.137.241","00:2580:19"   "192.168.137.174","00:3360:58". There is problem in the duration time.

Comment: @Ayu Can you please use a host that does not require a login? I can not access your file.

Comment: sure. Here is the link;    https://ufile.io/d42n7

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce your issue. I'll try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Ayu I fixed it. There was a stupid mistake in how the calculated time stamp difference in seconds got converted back to hours and minutes. It should work now.

Comment: It works great right now. It helps very much. Thank you again. Appreciate your help

Comment: Nice. You know where you find the accept button ;-D