# How to group variables based on time interval?

Tags: command-line, scripts

My `fb.csv` file is as below:

```
"Source","Time"  
"192.168.137.174","120025"
"10.0.138.163","120525"
"157.240.10.13","121036"
"157.240.10.13","122536"
"157.240.10.23","123041"
"157.240.10.23","123241"
"10.0.138.163","123352"
"192.168.137.174","123952"
"157.240.10.18","124152"
"157.240.10.18","124252"
"157.240.10.23","125653"
"157.240.10.23","130053"
"192.168.137.174","130102"
"10.0.138.163","130302"
"192.168.137.174","131007"
"192.168.137.174","131352"
"157.240.10.18","132552"
"157.240.10.18","132752"
"157.240.10.23","132953"
"157.240.10.23","133253"
"192.168.137.174","133502"
"10.0.138.163","134002"
"192.168.137.174","134507"
"192.168.137.174","135752"
"157.240.10.18","140052"
"157.240.10.18","140552"
"157.240.10.23","140653"
"157.240.10.23","141053"
"192.168.137.174","141402"
"10.0.138.163","141702"
"192.168.137.174","142707"
```

I would like to group (count) "Sources" for every 003000 (30 minutes) time interval.

Example Desired Output:

```
"Time Interval","Count of Sources"
"120000","4"
"123000","7"
"130000","8"
"133000","5"
"140000","7"
```

Is there any possible solution to this matter?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this entirely using only `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print"\"Time Interval\",\"Count of Sources\""}NR>1{gsub(/"/,"",$2);h=int($2/10000)*10000;m=int(($2-h)/3000)*3000;ctr[h+m]++}END{n=asorti(ctr,idx);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){print "\""idx[i]"\",\""ctr[idx[i]]"\""}}' fb.csv
```

For your given input file `fb.csv` this results in the output

```
"120000","4"
"123000","7"
"130000","8"
"133000","5"
"140000","7"
```

**Important:** This requires GNU AWK (`gawk`) to run, because it uses the `asorti(...)` function for sorting associative arrays by their indices. It does not work with `mawk`. You can find out your default `awk` version with using `awk -Wv`.

---

#### Explanation of the command:

We run `awk` like this here, setting the field separator that delimits columns to `,` and using the file `fb.csv` as input:

```
awk -F, '<COMMAND>' fb.csv
```

The `awk` command (placeholder `<COMMAND>` above) is this, after proper formatting:

```
BEGIN {
    print "\"Time Interval\",\"Count of Sources\""
}
NR>1 {
    gsub(/"/, "", $2)
    h = int($2 / 10000) * 10000
    m = int(($2-h) / 3000) * 3000
    ctr[h+m]++
}
END {
    n = asorti(ctr, idx)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print "\"" idx[i] "\",\"" ctr[idx[i]] "\""
    }
}
```

This looks horribly complicated (and I can't deny that it takes some thought to understand), so I'll try to break it up a bit:

The `BEGIN { ... }` code block will be executed once before the first line of input from the file is read. Then, for each but the first line ("line number greater than 1"), the `NR>1 { ... }` block is executed. Finally after all input is read, the `END { ... }` block will run.

- Now the `BEGIN` block is pretty straight-forward, it only prints the new CSV header line.
- Let's look at the `NR>1` block. Remember that `awk` splits each line into fields, which were separated by the field delimiter (the one we set to `,` using the `-F` argument). The first column/field will be stored in the variable `$1`, the second in `$2` and so on. We're only interested in the value of the second field, which contains the time.

  Using the `gsub(<PATTERN>, <REPLACEMENT>, <VARIABLE>)` function, we replace all occurrences of `<PATTERN>` (a regular expression enclosed in slashes, here it simply matches only the quotation marks) with a `<REPLACEMENT>` (empty, as we want to remove them) string in `<VARIABLE>` (`$2` i.e. the second filed containing the time here).

  Next we decode the time stamp into whole full hours `h` (multiplied with 10000) and whole half hours `m` (without the full hours; multiplied with 3000). We use an associative array `ctr` as counter of how often the rounded time stamp `h+m` occurs in the input.
- Finally in the `END` block, we print out the counter's values [sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458455/4464570) by the rounded time stamp indices.

Comment: It returns: `awk: line 2: function asorti never defined`. I found this function belongs to the package [`gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting.html). 
After `sudo apt install gawk` the function is available also for `awk`.

Comment: @Byte Commander I tried and my output for the time and count: "0","200". There is problem and I dont know what it is.

Comment: @Ayu Can you share the exact input you used so that I can try to reproduce your issue? If ti is long, maybe upload it to a https://pastebin.com instead of editing your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is more elegant way, but my suggestion is to create an executable file, let's call it `counter.bash`, with this script content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo '"Time Interval","Count of Sources"'
FILTRED=$(tail -n +2 "$1" | sed -e 's/^.*\,//' -e 's/"//g' | sort)
T=1

while [ $T -lt 24 ]; do

        ((T++)); R1=0; R2=0

        for i in $FILTRED; do

                hour=${i::-4}; minute=${i:2:-2}

                if [ "$T" -lt "10" ]; then TT="0${T}"; else TT="${T}"; fi

                if [ "$minute" -lt "30" ]; then
                        if [ "$hour" == "$TT" ]; then ((R1++)); fi
                else
                        if [ "$hour" == "$TT" ]; then ((R2++)); fi
                fi
        done

        if [ "$R1" -ne "0" ]; then echo "\"${TT}0000\",\"$R1\""; fi
        if [ "$R2" -ne "0" ]; then echo "\"${TT}3000\",\"$R2\""; fi
done
```

Then run:

```
./counter.bash fb.csv
```

If the result is adequate redirect the output to a new file:

```
./counter.bash fb.csv > fb.counted.csv
```

---

I've compared the performance of Byte Commander's answer and this script, both  applied on the same not so huge file. They are just incomparable:

```bsh
$ cat fb.csv | wc -l
3304


$ time awk -F, 'BEGIN{print"\"Time Interval\",\"Count of Sources\""}NR>1{gsub(/"/,"",$2);h=int($2/10000)*10000;m=int(($2-h)/3000)*3000;ctr[h+m]++}END{n=asorti(ctr,idx);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){print "\""idx[i]"\",\""ctr[idx[i]]"\""}}' fb.csv

"Time Interval","Count of Sources"
"120000","672"
"123000","672"
"130000","560"
"133000","560"
"140000","839"

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s


$ time ./counter.bash fb.csv

"Time Interval","Count of Sources"
"120000","672"
"123000","672"
"130000","560"
"133000","560"
"140000","839"

real    0m2.374s
user    0m2.368s
sys     0m0.000s
```

When the file is really huge my script just crashes (on different lines) after a long while:

```bsh
$ cat fb.csv | wc -l
9303745


$ time awk -F, 'BEGIN{print"\"Time Interval\",\"Count of Sources\""}NR>1{gsub(/"/,"",$2);h=int($2/10000)*10000;m=int(($2-h)/3000)*3000;ctr[h+m]++}END{n=asorti(ctr,idx);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){print "\""idx[i]"\",\""ctr[idx[i]]"\""}}' fb.csv

"Time Interval","Count of Sources"
"120000","1892288"
"123000","1892290"
"130000","1576904"
"133000","1576905"
"140000","2365357"

real    0m23.193s
user    0m23.080s
sys     0m0.096s


$ time ./counter.bash fb.csv

"Time Interval","Count of Sources"
./counter.bash: line 17: [: .0.138.1: integer expression expected
^C
real    2m27.992s
user    2m27.940s
sys     0m1.636s
```

Comment: Thanks @pa4080. I tried to run the bash script. But I got error "./counter.bash: line 21:[ integer expression expected". How to solve this? Thanks

Comment: @Ayu, just use the `awk` approach :)

Comment: I tried but this  is my output: "Time Interval","Count Of Sources" "0","200". There is problem and I dont know what it is.

Comment: @Ayu, maybe there is something wrong with the file format. Within which OS it is generated? Could you share it as file somewhere, I will try it at home, later this evening.

Comment: I already found the problem. There was problem in the format and it is fixed already. Thanks

Comment: just want to ask different question. If you dont mind in helping me to solve this problem. This is the link; https://askubuntu.com/questions/955886/find-the-difference-value-between-the-longest-time-and-shortest-time-of-the-same?noredirect=1#comment1524911_955886